# how do you retrieve xml data from nested nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
<CustomerOrders>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10643</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-08-25</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10692</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-10-03</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>ANATR</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10308</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>ANATR</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1996-09-18</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
</CustomerOrders>
```

How do you retrieve OrderID,CustomerID and OrderDate? i have been trying it for hours already. Can someone help me? Thanks!

```
XmlNodeList xmlnode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Customers"); 
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div"); 
for(int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count; i++) 
{ 
    Label lbl2 = new Label();
    lbl2.Text = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes[1].Name;
    div.Controls.Add(lbl2); 
    RadioButtonList rb1 = new RadioButtonList(); 
    rb1.Items.Add(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes[1].InnerText+"<br>"); 
    div.Controls.Add(rb1); 
} 
div1.Controls.Add(div);
```

Comment: I have tried .childnodes. but what i get is having them all sticking together.

Comment: What i intend to do is to populate RadioButtonList with orderID,CustomerID and OrderDate. (I know it doesnt make sense. Its just a practice)

Comment: `code`   
        XmlNodeList xmlnode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Customers");

        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
       for(int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
        {
          
            Label lbl2 = new Label();
            lbl2.Text = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes[1].Name;
            div.Controls.Add(lbl2);
            RadioButtonList rb1 = new RadioButtonList();
            rb1.Items.Add(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes[1].InnerText+"<br>");
            div.Controls.Add(rb1);
        }
   
       


        div1.Controls.Add(div);

Comment: @Lokii you can edit your own question to add relevant information. No need to comment unreadable code here.

Comment: @Marco I added the code.

Comment: rather confusing that you named the ordertag Orders, since it is an order, and not a collection of orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml("yourxmldata");

                XmlNodeList customers = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Customers");

                foreach (XmlNode customer in customers)
                {
                    XmlNodeList customerOrders = customer.SelectNodes("Orders");

                    string customername = customer["CustomerID"].InnerText;

                    foreach (XmlNode customerOrder in customerOrders)
                    {
                        string orderid = customerOrder["OrderID"].InnerText;
                        string orderdate = customerOrder["OrderDate"].InnerText;
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XDocument class and its decendants. You can use XPath expressions to delve deeper into the code:

e.g.

```
using System.Xml.Linq
using System.Xml.XPath

.... 
XDocument doc= XDocument.Load("sample.xml");
XElement root= doc.Element("CustomerOrders");
var result= root.XPathSelectElements("Customers/CustomerId");
foreach(var customerid in result)
    {
    .....
    }
```

Depending on what you want to achieve this should put you at the right track. While I was typing the answer, another answer proposes to use XmlDocument class. That should work as well, but when using XDocument you can use Linq, which adds a lot of flexibilty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is everything using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication47
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Customers").Select(x => new
            {
                customerID = (string)x.Element("CustomerID"),
                companyName = (string)x.Element("CompanyName"),
                orders = x.Elements("Orders").Select(y => new {      
                   orderID = (int)y.Element("OrderID"),
                   customerID = (string)y.Element("CustomerID"),
                   date =  (DateTime)y.Element("OrderDate")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```